# jquery deferred - "always" called at the first reject

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm using `$.when` to chain some Deferred objects, and if one of them fail, the `always` method will be called directly after the failure, even if I still have some deferrer in a "pending" state.

```
var promises = [], defs = [];

for(var i=0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
    defs.push($.Deferred());
    promises.push(defs[i].promise());
}

var res = $.when.apply($, promises);

res.fail(function(){console.log('failed')});
res.done(function(){console.log('done')});
res.always(function(){console.log('always')});
res.then(function(){console.log('then, done')},      
         function(){console.log('then, failed')});        

var j = 0;                      
var t = setInterval(function(){
    if(j < 10){
        if(j < 5) {
            console.log('resolve');
            defs[j++].resolve();    
        }
        else {
            console.log('reject');
            defs[j++].reject();
        }
    }
    else {
        clearInterval(t);        
    }
}, 200);
```

Check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cSy2K/1/).

Maybe it's the normal behavior. But, in this case, how can I catch the end of my chain even if some of them have failed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's by design: The method will resolve its master Deferred as soon as all the Deferreds resolve, or reject the master Deferred as soon as **one** of the Deferreds is rejected.
[...]
Note that some of the Deferreds may still be **unresolved** at that point.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

You can save references to all deferreds and track them separately.

Something like this:

```
var whenAll = function() {
   var dfd = $.Deferred(),
       len = arguments.length,
       counter = 0,
       state = "resolved",
       resolveOrReject = function() {
           if(this.state() === "rejected"){
               state = "rejected";
           }
           counter++;

           if(counter === len) {
               dfd[state === "rejected"? "reject": "resolve"]();   
           }

       };


    $.each(arguments, function(idx, item) {
        item.always(resolveOrReject); 
    });

   return dfd.promise();    
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cSy2K/2/

Comment: thanks @yury-tarabanko ! I like the idea to extend jQuery and add a reusable method to look at all deferrer end, even if they failed. Based on your idea and on "when" jQuery source, i did the "whenAll" again, check the source if you have time http://jsfiddle.net/cSy2K/5/ ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is normal behavior. If one fails, the thing that relies on all fails as well. See also the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

So, you either have to track them manually, or you feed only resolved Promises into `when`:

```
promises.push( defs[i].promise().then(function(x) {
      return {result:x,resolved:true};
  }, function(x) {
      return (new $.Deferred).resolve({result:x,resolved:false});
  })
);
```

With this, your `res` will only call the `done` callback when all promises are processed, and it will get an array of objects indicating status and result of them.